# Future task just vanishes

Tags: c++, c++11, future

I run into a rather strange situation when using `std::future` and `ThreadPool`, though I do not think it's `ThreadPool` (I'm using https://github.com/bandi13/ThreadPool/blob/master/example.cpp) since (I've tried multiple forks of it and after some debugging I do not see how it would be related to the issue).

The issue is that under certain situation my `doProcess` method just goes nirvana - it does not return. It just disappears midst of a long running loop.

Therefore I think I must be doing something wrong, but can't figure out what.

Here's the code:

```
ThreadPool pool(numThreads);
std::vector< std::future<bool> > futures;

int count = 0;
string orgOut = outFile;
for (auto fileToProcess : filesToProcess) {
    count++;
    outFile = orgOut + std::to_string(count);

    // enque processing in the thread pool
    futures.emplace_back(
        pool.enqueue([count, fileToProcess, outFile, filteredKeys, sql] {
            return doProcess(fileToProcess, outFile, filteredKeys, sql);
        })
    );
}
```

Then I wait for all processings to be done (I think this could be done in a more elegant way also):

```
bool done = false;
    while (!done) {
        done = true;
        for (auto && futr : futures) {
            auto status = futr.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
            if (status != std::future_status::ready) {
                done = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: At first I also tried the obvius wait(), with the same result however:

```
bool done = false;
while (!done) {
    done = true;
    for (auto && futr : futures) {
        futr.wait();
    }
}
```

Edit: The doProcess() method. The behavior is this: The loopcnt variable is just a counter to debug how often the method was entered and the loop started. As you can see, there is no return from this loop, but the thread just vanishes when inside this loop with no error whatsoever and wasHereCnt is reached only occasionally (like 1 of 100 times the method is run). I'm really puzzled.

```
bool doProcess([...]) {
    // ....
    vector<vector<KVO*>*>& features = filter.result();
    vector<vector<KVO*>*> filteredFeatures;
    static int loopcnt = 0;
    std::cout << "loops " << loopcnt << endl;
    loopcnt++;
    for (vector<KVO*>* feature : features) {
        for (KVO *kv : *feature) {
            switch (kv->value.type()) {
                case Variant::JNULL:
                    sqlFilter.setNullValue(kv->key);
                    break;

                    case Variant::INT:
                    sqlFilter.setValue(static_cast<int64_t>(kv->value), kv->key);
                    break;

                case Variant::UINT:
                    sqlFilter.setValue(static_cast<int64_t>(kv->value), kv->key);
                    break;

                case Variant::DOUBLE:
                    sqlFilter.setValue(static_cast<double>(kv->value), kv->key);
                    break;

                case Variant::STRING:
                    sqlFilter.setValue(static_cast<string>(kv->value), kv->key);
                    break;

                default:
                    assert(false);
                    break;
            }
        }
        int filterResult = sqlFilter.exec();
        if (filterResult > 0) {
            filteredFeatures.push_back(feature);
        }
        sqlFilter.reset();
     }

    static int wasHereCnt = 0;
    std::cout << "was here: " << wasHereCnt << endl;
    wasHereCnt++;

    JsonWriter<Writer<FileWriteStream>> geojsonWriter(writer, filteredFeatures);
        bool res = geojsonWriter.write();
        os.Flush();
        fclose(fp);

        return res;
}
```

The `doProcess` method does work when it's taking less time. It breaks and disappears when it takes somewhat more time. The difference being just the complexity of an SQL query I run in the method. So I don't post the code for `doProcess()`.

What causes the thread of the thread pool to be interrupted, and how to fix it?

**UPDATE**

Well, I found it out. After several hours I decided to remove the future tasks and just ran the task on the main thread. The issue was that an exception was thrown via:

throw std::runtime_error("bad cast");

... some time down the code flow after this:

```
case Variant::UINT:
                sqlFilter.setValue(static_cast<int64_t>(kv->value), kv->key);
                break;
```

This error was thrown as expected when running on the main thread. But it's never raised when run as future task. This is really odd and seems like a compiler or debugger issue.

Comment: does the behavior changes if you do `==timeout` instead of `!= ready` ? is there a chance that future throws? have you tried to check every future for `valid()` before waiting?

Comment: Why not simply do `for (auto&& fut : futures) { fut.wait(); }` in your last snippet ?

Comment: @Jarod42 That's what I did at first. Same behavior. I've updated the question.

Comment: @OlegBogdanov Same behavior

Comment: i hope your threadpool is not local variable in some method ;)

Comment: ThreadPool is a local variable in main() (first code snippet above)

Comment: just to exclude some weird local issues of your stl implementation: `enqueue` returns shared_future, as uses example you have linked. have you tried to use vector of them instead of vector of futures? Cant directly say if that could be a reason

Comment: shared_future makes no difference unfortunately.

Comment: Did you have exception handlers on your thread? Unhandled thread exception is supposed to terminate the program.

Comment: @M.M The issue would have been easy to catch if this had been the case. There was no try/catch enclosing above mentioned cast exception. And there is no exception handler in the ThreadPool lib either. Instead of crashing the app the thread just disappeared without any trace that it broke.